# Change last character in found sequences

Tags: sed, replace

I want to change every first `/` in side `\ukindex` into `!`.

E.g. `\ukindex{duality/weak|)}%` becomes `\ukindex{duality!weak|)}%`.

I can find all such occurrences with `grep linear-programming.tex -e '\ukindex{[^/^}]\+/'`.

But, i don't know how to write corresponding `sed` for it. This doesn't work:

```
 sed -i 's/\ukindex{[^/^}]\+//\ukindex{[^/^}]\+!/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it works like this

```
sed -i 's/\(\ukindex{[^/^}]\+\)\//\1!/g'
```

- `()` in the first part define groups (strings in fact) that can be reused in the the second part
- `\1` in the second part are references to the first group captured in the first part